# How to reuse a function defined in another bash file?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a utility function that I used a lot (`assertReturnStatus()`). I'd like to define it in a utility file (`utility.sh`) and reuse it in other bash scripts.

How can reuse the function from another bash script file? Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to "import" the first file in the second.

Be warned that this will litterally include the first, so any code in the first will be executed as if it were litterally in the place of the line.

The syntax is:

```
# if /path/to/file exists, then include it
[ -f /path/to/file ] && . /path/to/file
```

Note `bash` also support the keyword `source` (ie: `source /path/to/file`) but it is not POSIX compliant and might not work in other shell like `ash`, `dash`, `posh`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do an explicit sourcing of your script file as [bufh suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31715558/520162): I put my often used functions in my `.bashrc` which gets always sourced thus having the functions always available.

As bufh pointed out in a comment *always* is not really always but limited to interactive shells. So, if you're planning to use the scripts from an interactive session, you could put it into the `.bashrc`, otherwise go for explicit sourcing.

Comment: Good idea, but be careful as they wont be available from another script (ie: one of your crontab or a remote ssh) since your `.bashrc` is sourced only when your shell run in interactive mode and `.profile` when run by login.